# How can i remotely debug an android app installed on a far distant user's mobile?

Tags: android, android-testing

I have a situation. My client says they are facing some issue (not a crash) while using the app. We have tried all our ways that could help fixing it. But nothing works out. The best we can do is to travel to client's location- Connect the device to a PC and the debug the issue while inspecting the entire logs. Can all this be avoided? Any app that the client can install and send us the entire logs of app running.

Comment: You can Use Fabric Crash Reporting LIbrary in your app

Comment: how about writing logs to a file and getting that file.

Comment: ask client to install team viewer on his device and then you can debug the app for functionality by remotely connecting to that device.

Or you can check where the client is facing issue in the app, create a file and store logs/action/events by yourself. And after performing the task get the file using above method (remote connection).

Comment: @KaranMer How to create a log file?

Comment: Write all your log string in text based file.